# GVIM 6.4 has better GUI and options than GVIM 7

Tags: linux, vim

I wanted to use tab file feature of gvim, hence I moved to gvim 7.0 from gvim 6.4.6 since older one does not support it. However to my amazement I see much better GUI in my older gvim. Not only the appearance but options are also less. For example in the "Edit" menu there is no select font option which was there in GVIM 6.4.6.

Do I need to change something (.vimrc etc) to have GUI and features better than 6.4.6? Attach is the screenshot showing new vs old to give you an idea...

Thanks for the help 
Newbie
    [image: New GVIM vs Old]

Comment: Which distribution packages did you use for each? If you compiled from source, which `./configure` options did you use for each? (I have a feeling that your newer one needs a `--enable-gui=gtk2` or `--enable-gui=gnome2` option...)

Comment: Actually I am on a server which uses `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server` OS. I am using `KDE Desktop Environment`. I did not compile GVIM. Server has both versions of GVIM and I am just using them! Could you please tell me about why do you think these options are needed?

Comment: The Version 7.0 screenshot looks like the old hand-drawn X widgets that used to be popular about twenty years ago (see the `xfontsel` program for another quick example). The Version 6.4 screenshot is using either the GTK or the Gnome widgets -- I'm not sure which (and I haven't got a clue what the difference is between them -- I think just gnome-vfs layer in gnome, but no promises there).

Comment: Which GVim package did you install?  Distributions often create separate ones for the Motif/Lesstif, Gtk, and Gnome variants.

Comment: I got it. There are multiple 7.0 versions and I picked up another one that works. Thanks @sarnold and ephemient

Comment: @Newbie: could you add an answer saying which package you uninstalled and which package you installed?

Comment: @sarnold: I did not modify anything...that particular GVIM was already available and I just used that...I want to give more meaningful answer...by mentioning what graphics style my current GVIM is using (like Motif, GTK2 etc) but how to check that? I will post the description as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges. Vim can be compiled with different GUI toolkits, and your newer, less-appealing looking one was compiled without the modern GTK2 GUI.

You can check this via `:version`. Try to get a different Vim build.

Comment: Thanks for the command Ingo. At the time of asking question I did not know about tool kits and also I did not know how to check with what toolkit my VIM is compiled...

Comment: Thank you for accepting and closing the question. I've been going over all old unanswered Vim questions and tried to bring closure to them.